# Firebase unable to display name from realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase database I have created a new user and have asigned some values to that user.

[image: See attached image]

However I'm not able to fetch the name and display in the header in my navigation drawer. I'm posting my full `MainActivity.class` for the sake of clarity.

Please help me figure this out, tell me what Im doing wrong, **I have been on this all day**.

```
package com.company.walt.activities;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IProgressDisplay, ISoftKeyboard, IFirebaseAuth {

    // STATIC
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int USER_DASHBOARD = 1;
    private static final int PROFILE_MANAGE = 2;
    private static final int PROFILE_SETTING = 3;

    // FIREBASE
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    /*
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    private DatabaseReference reference = databaseReference.child(getString(R.string.dbnode_users));
    */


    DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mConditionRef = mRootRef.child("users");


    // VARIABLES
    private ToggleButton mToogleButton;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private AccountHeader mHeaderResult = null;
    private Drawer mResult = null;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private String currentName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.NightTheme);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        switchAppTheme();

        createToolbar();

        buildHeader(false, savedInstanceState);

        createDrawerBuilder();

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkAuthenticationState();
    }

    /**
     * Used to check if user is authenticated or not
     */
    private void checkAuthenticationState() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkAuthenticationState: checking authentication state.");
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkAuthenticationState: user is null, navigating back to login screen.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkAuthenticationState: user is authenticated.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to switch between light and dark mode
     */
    public void switchAppTheme() {

        mToogleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.switcher);

        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            mToogleButton.setChecked(true);
        }

        mToogleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    restartApp();
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    restartApp();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Used to create the toolbar on top
     */
    private void createToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    /**
     * small helper method to reuse the logic to build the AccountHeader
     * this will be used to replace the header of the drawer with a compact/normal header
     *
     * @param compact
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    private void buildHeader(boolean compact, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        IProfile profile;

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {

            String email = user.getEmail();

            profile = new ProfileDrawerItem()
                    .withIdentifier(USER_DASHBOARD)
                    .withName(getCurrentName())
                    .withEmail(email)
                    .withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_img));

            mHeaderResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()

                    .withActivity(this)
                    .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.ip_menu_header_bg)
                    .withCompactStyle(compact)
                    .addProfiles(
                            profile,

                            new ProfileSettingDrawerItem()
                                    .withIdentifier(PROFILE_MANAGE)
                                    .withName("Manage Account")
                                    .withDescription("Manage your details")
                                    .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings)
                                            .actionBar().colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text)),

                            new ProfileSettingDrawerItem()
                                    .withIdentifier(PROFILE_SETTING)
                                    .withName("Add Account")
                                    .withDescription("Register new account")
                                    .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_person_add)
                                            .actionBar().colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text))

                    )
                    .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {

                            //sample usage of the onProfileChanged listener
                            //if the clicked item has the identifier 1 add a new profile ;)

                            if (profile instanceof IDrawerItem && ((IDrawerItem) profile).getIdentifier() == USER_DASHBOARD) {
                                // Navigate to home fragment
                                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                                Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

                                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
                                transaction.commit();

                            }

                            if (profile instanceof IDrawerItem && ((IDrawerItem) profile).getIdentifier() == PROFILE_MANAGE) {
                                // Navigate to home fragment
                                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                                Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

                                fragment = new AccountFragment();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
                                transaction.commit();

                            } else if (profile instanceof IDrawerItem && ((IDrawerItem) profile).getIdentifier() == PROFILE_SETTING) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ACCOUNT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

        }

    }


    /**
     * Used to create the drawer with all the icons and items
     */
    private void createDrawerBuilder() {
        //create the drawer and remember the `Drawer` mResult object
        mResult = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withAccountHeader(mHeaderResult)
                .withToolbar(mToolbar)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("1st")
                                .withIdentifier(1)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_device_hub))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("2nd")
                                .withIdentifier(2)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_shopping_cart))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("3rd")
                                .withIdentifier(3)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_camera_roll))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("4th")
                                .withIdentifier(4)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_content_copy))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("5th")
                                .withIdentifier(5)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_folder_open))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_section_header).withEnabled(false),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("6th")
                                .withIdentifier(6)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("7th")
                                .withIdentifier(7)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_headset_mic))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("8th")
                                .withIdentifier(8)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_security))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("9th")
                                .withIdentifier(9)
                                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_power_settings_new))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn")

                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                        navigateDrawerItem((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier(), drawerItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .addStickyDrawerItems(
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_all_right_reserved).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_copyright).withEnabled(false)
                ).build();

    }

    /**
     * Used to navigate to drawer fragment items
     */
    public void navigateDrawerItem(int pos, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;

        switch (pos) {
            case 1:
                fragmentClass = Fragment1.class;
                break;
            case 2:
                fragmentClass = Fragment2.class;
                break;
            case 3:
                fragmentClass = Fragment3.class;
                break;
            case 4:
                fragmentClass = Fragment4.class;
                break;
            case 5:
                fragmentClass = Fragment5.class;
                break;
            case 6:
                fragmentClass = Fragment6.class;
                break;
            case 7:
                fragmentClass = Fragment7.class;
                break;
            case 8:
                fragmentClass = Fragment8.class;
                break;

            case 9:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                signOut();
                restartApp();
                break;

            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        mResult.closeDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
        outState = mResult.saveInstanceState(outState);

        //add the values which need to be saved from the accountHeader to the bundle
        outState = mHeaderResult.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
        if (mResult != null && mResult.isDrawerOpen()) {
            mResult.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign out from application
     */
    private void signOut() {
        Log.d(TAG, "signOut: signing out");
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    }

    /**
     * Used to restart the application
     */
    private void restartApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Query query = mConditionRef.orderByKey().equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot singelSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    User user = singelSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    setCurrentName(user.getName());

                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " + user.toString());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }

    /*
   * **********************************************************************************************
   * GET & SET
   * */

    public String getCurrentName() {
        return this.currentName;
    }

    //public method to set the age variable
    public void setCurrentName(String name) {
        this.currentName = name;
    }

    /*
    * **********************************************************************************************
    * INTERFACE METHODS
    * */

    /**
     * Display progressbar
     */
    public void showProgress() {
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     * Hide progressbar
     */
    public void hideProgress() {
        if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hide softKeyboard
     */
    public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    /*
    * **********************************************************************************************
    * FIREBASE SETUP
    * */

    /**
     * Firebase Auth
     */
    public void setupFirebaseAuth() {

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    //toastMessage("Successfully signed in with: " + user.getEmail());


                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        };

    }

}
```

This is output in the LogCat

```
01-01 20:30:24.294 4992-4992/com.company.walt D/MainActivity: onDataChange: found user: User{name='Ben Solo', phone='0997755223311', profile_img='', user_id='D1lXejIFjNTcRr87PAI8rdjm7Wt2'}
```

Comment: is your log inside the onDataChange printing any values?

Answer (score 1):

The onDataChange method is Asynchronous unlike other synchronous method calls.

This means that code after the listener declaration will most likely run before your onDataChange gets the call and sets the user name. This will cause your name to be null in your display

shift the current user code to setCurrentName method

```
 setCurrentName(String name){

        currentUser = new ProfileDrawerItem()
            .withIdentifier(USER_DASHBOARD)

            // Using name passed by onDataChange
            .withName(name)

            .withEmail(email)
            .withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_img));

 }
```

Now your display will get the name when onDataChange gets called and should update is as per your logic

Comment: It is not really working, please take a look at my updated code!
I have tried different approaches to this but all have failed